# jquery with ASP.NET MVC dynamic pagination generation

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to generate enough pagination links accordingly to amount of job offers. (I am building something related to job searching).

I am trying to call Send function after click event but I have another jQuery targeting that list.

```
<li class="active page-number"><a href="#" onclick="Send(2)">2</a></li>

<script>
    ///Custom scripts
    ///
    function Send(page) {
       $.post("/JobOffer/JobList/", { page: page });
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".pagination>li").click(function () {
            $(".pagination>li.active").removeClass("active");
            $(this).addClass("active");
        });
    });
</script>
```

So when I click on ".pagination>li" I go to Action JobList in JobOffer controller marked with [HttpPost].

```
  [HttpPost]
  public ActionResult JobList(int? page)
  {
        var pageNumber = page ?? 1;
        var pageSize = 3;

        /*Some magic*/

        viewModel.OfferCount = GetJobOfferCount(Enums.JobOfferType.Employer);
        viewModel.PageSize = pageSize;

        return View(viewModel);
  }
```

And then I receive page parameter as null.

How could I send page parameter to my action method?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the `@Url.Action()` helper with the overload that takes `Action` and `Controller` name. And modify your html to take advantage of the `data-attribute`. Just a simplified solution of your problem. Try this:

```
<li class="active page-number"><a href="#" data-page="2">2</a></li>

$(document).ready(function () {

    $("a").click(function () {
        var page = $(this).data("page");            
        $.post("@Url.Action("JobList","JobOffer")", { page: page });

        $(this).parent().toggleClass("active");
    });


});
```